# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' ' ---> the quotation is throwing me off

Tags: python, bash

First time here! Please go easy. I have a problem running a python script for my file. I'm reading up on "learn python the hard way" - Zed shaw. On example 15: learning to read files by creating two files (ex15.py and ex15_newfile.txt). I had this file run before and while doing my challenge later in the book, an odd error popped. I went back and tried to cross reference. Since it worked the last time, I thought no problem, so re-run and it doesn't work. I find it hard to believe the file moved on it's own.

It's the quotation after "No such file or directory: (' ')" that I have no idea. Clearly the file is reading my example txt, but printing again, it doesn't understand. I reviewed multiple similar questions - creating new path, copying the actual path, making sure it's not txt.txt file. Slept on it for a few days and no luck. Any pointers would be great!

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your file {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = input(">")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())

txt.close
txt_again.close
```

The terminal returns:

```
Here's your file ex15_newfile.txt:
This is a text note
Why is this not working
Who are you 

Type the filename again:
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex15.py", line 13, in <module>
    txt_again = open(file_again)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Comment: `input` is a function used to get information from the user. So, you should type the `filename` for your program to run

Comment: Pressing the return key here `file_again = input(">")` and not typing the filename produces a empty string `''` that the `open()` function is erroring on.

Comment: you are a life saver. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to type the filename again after > in terminal.
If you type: ex15_newfile.txt it should work.